# Sending email from Objective c using an specific email account

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, accounts

We need to send an email directly form an App, but using the specific company e-mail account. That is, a user may have several e-mail accounts in his iphone but the app needs to get automatically the user's company e-mail, and so sending the message from this account.

We've tried several ways without success. To send the e-mail, we use the SKPSMTPMessage.

We've been able to access all the contacts with the Address Book framework, but we cannot acess the user e-mail.

Do you know any way to do it? We've been browsing this web site and others without much success.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using SKPSMTPMessage, that means you are not using iphone mail accounts (in that case use MFMailComposeViewController). So the first time user tries to send email ask for login details and store them in the app

Comment: Thank you; eventually we used MFMailComposeViewController to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple don't allow this for the security of the app users. **Apple won't allow you to send email or give you access to users email without his permission.**